# Cannot find module 'mssql' nodejs

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I'm beginner in Node.js, I want to connect Node.js with local SQL server and I got this sentence:

> Cannot find module 'mssql' nodejs

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just run '`npm install mssql`' ---
In case after setup, you got : [...].Connection is not a constructor ==> run '`npm uninstall mssql`' and put version when install => '`npm install mssql@3.3.0`'

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Nowdays (2021) you have to read [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) manual.

And basically you have to install **Microsoft SQL Server client for Node.js** like

```
npm install mssql
```

You can test it by following code.

**test-mssql-server.js**

```
var app = require('express')();

app.get('*', (req, res) =>  {
  
    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'mypssssss1!',
        server: 'MyComputerName001\\SQL2016Instance', 
        database: 'MyDbName' 
    };

    (async function () {
        try {
            let pool = await sql.connect(config)

            let result1 = await pool.request()                
                .query('select * from Devices')
   
            // console.dir(result1) 
            // send records as a response
            res.send(result1);
        } catch (err) {
            //  error checks
        }
    })();
    
    sql.on('error', err => {
        // error handler
        console.log(err);
    });

    
});

//start listening
var port = process.env.PORT || 5321;
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Application started on ' + new Date());
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

After this start your **node.js** app in command prompt

```
node test-mssql-server.js
```

Now open your browser and go to `http://localhost:5321/`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have the node module installed in your system.
Install this using
`npm install mssql`